# Is there a way to return a list of the default image size names when they are unset?

Tags: images

With `intermediate_image_sizes`, there's the option to unset default image sizes e.g. `thumbnail`, `medium` and so on.

Using `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` returns the remaining list of image sizes which may include custom sizes.

Is there a way to retrieve the default image size names e.g. `thumbnail` without hardcoding these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` before applying the filter (`intermediate_image_sizes`). Or, temporarily remove the filter, call the function to store the output, and then re-apply the filter.

If you only want the list of default image sizes, then you can remove the values returned by `wp_get_additional_image_sizes()` from those returned by `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` (untested):

```php
remove_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', ... );

$image_sizes         = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
$addtl_image_sizes   = wp_get_additional_image_sizes();
$default_image_sizes = array_diff( $image_sizes, $addtl_image_sizes );

add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', ... );
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand on `Call get_intermediate_image_sizes() before applying the filter (intermediate_image_sizes).`. Do you mean remove `intermediate_image_sizes`? If yes, wouldn't I still have to match the values to store it e.g.. `in_array`?

Comment: Updated my answer. If it's not helpful, you may receive a better answer if you post a new question explaining your ultimate objective.